# JBoss EAP: @TransactionTimeout not affecting @Timeout Method?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, jta

Here I have a piece of code which is triggered by an EJB Timer, running inside an EAR deployed on a JBoss EAP 6.2.

Since processing within the `onTimeout(Timer timer)` method can take much longer than the default transaction timeout specified in standalone.xml I came up with this solution:

```
//[...]
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout;
//[...]

@Startup
@Singleton
public class DataqReaderServiceImpl extends AbstractDataqReaderService {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Override
    @Timeout
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @TransactionTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, value = 60)
    protected void onTimeout(Timer timer) {
    try {
            super.readDataq(timer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
//[...]
```

But appearantly the `@TransactionTimeout` annotation is ignored. After the code has been running for 5 Minutes, the Transaction Reaper comes to live:

```
2016-12-19 15:12:21,878 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff0a07065b:296fc7c:5857e084:67ef in state  RUN
2016-12-19 15:12:21,881 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff0a07065b:296fc7c:5857e084:67ef invoked while multiple threads active within it.
2016-12-19 15:12:21,881 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action     0:ffff0a07065b:296fc7c:5857e084:67ef aborting with 1 threads active!
2016-12-19 15:12:21,882 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff0a07065b:296fc7c:5857e084:67ef
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Try change to public method. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-850

Answer (score 0):

After trying some more I found that this seems to be a bug in RedHat JBoss EAP 6.2.

Here's a tracelog of where the transaction starts on EAP 6.2.0:

```
2016-12-20 07:21:29,754 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (EJB default - 10) TransactionReaper::insert ( BasicAction: 0:ffff0a07065b:-60e989f1:5858dbac:45 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING, 300 )
2016-12-20 07:21:29,754 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (EJB default - 10) ReaperElement::ReaperElement ( BasicAction: 0:ffff0a07065b:-60e989f1:5858dbac:45 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING, 300 )
```

The second argument logged for TransactionReaper::insert is the timeout value.

Now here's a tracelog of the same event, but on EAP 6.4.8 (I verified that the default timeout is set to 300 seconds in the 6.2.0 and the 6.4.8 instance):

```
09:12:52,913 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (EJB default - 8) TransactionReaper::insert ( BasicAction: 0:ffff0a076537:-1ab57a18:5858f5d6:31 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING, 3600 )
09:12:52,913 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (EJB default - 8) ReaperElement::ReaperElement ( BasicAction: 0:ffff0a076537:-1ab57a18:5858f5d6:31 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING, 3600 )
```

So the transaction is initiated with the correct timeout value on EAP 6.4.8.

Comment: I now have a comparable problem on Wildfly 17.0.1 - On my machine it works and on my prod system (same JDK, same WF version) the Transaction gets killed after 5minutes.
I even inserted a lookup of the transactionManager at begin of the long running transaction ant "getTimeout()" gets my correct 3600s - but thee transaction gets "reaped" after 5mins (300s).
Completely buggy: watching the status of the transaction inside the long running task gives Status.RUNNING (=0) - WHICH IS NOT TRUE.

Comment: This is really annoying since tests of the configuration issue take really looong ... much time consuming.

Comment: I've got it "working" now: I've added the attribute "default-timeout" to the transaction configuration to increase general transaction timeouts (standalone.xml). Fun fact: it seems that THIS default-timeout doesn't get obeyed - but now my annotation value is used. I don't get it what's wrong here. 
I think it might be a bug. If I encounter it again I'll simply change my docker-compose file to next wildfly version.